# Test ajax call with qunit and mockjax

Tags: knockout.js, qunit, mockjax

I'm trying to test that an ajax call. I need to test that the correct url is called, with the correct data and result. Starting off with this test which fails. The error I get is "Expected: saved, Actual: ".

Function in my knockout viewmodel -

```
self.functions.save = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/x',
        data: { test: "" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            self.saved(response.message);
        }
    });
};
```

Qunit test -

```
test('save does ajax call', function () {
        $.mockjax({
            url: '/x',
            dataType: 'json',
            responseText:
                {
                    message: 'saved'
                }
        });
        mock.functions.save();
        equal(mock.saved(), "saved");
});
```

Comment: You should put a `console.log(response)` statement in your success callback to see that your mockajax properly configured and returned the expected response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the order of execution. Your `save()` method performs an asynchronous action, and Mockjax respects that. So when you call `mock.functions.save();` in your test, that function *immediately returns*, which means your `equal()` assertion fires before the `success` handler of the ajax call in your source code. You'll need to add some way for the test to know when the Ajax call has completed. In the example below I've used a simple callback, but you could also do this with Promises or some other method.

Source code:

```
self.functions.save = function (callback) {
    callback = callback || function(){};  // ensure we have a callback
    $.ajax({
        url: '/x',
        data: { test: "" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            self.saved(response.message);
        },
        // when the call is finished, execute the callback (success or error)
        complete: function () {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

In your test, you need to use QUnit's async ability. There is a [new way to do async testing in v1.16.0](http://api.qunitjs.com/async/), so either update, or you can look up [the old way](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.asyncTest/):

```
QUnit.test('save does ajax call', function (assert) {
    // first tell QUnit you need to perform async actions...
    var done = QUnit.async();

    $.mockjax({
        url: '/x',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText:
            {
                message: 'saved'
            }
    });
    mock.functions.save(function() {
        // this callback fires when the async action is complete,
        // so now we do our assertions
        assert.equal(mock.saved(), "saved");

        // ...and now we tell QUnit we're done with async actions
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: It would work, but the approach of introducing additional code into the code-base for the sake of testing just sounds wrong.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. This isn't introducing arbitrary additional code lines in the source, it's introducing a callback function to inform any calling code that the asynchronous action has completed. Without that there is no way to test this method unless you set an arbitrary timeout, which is really poor testing practice. In other words, the code isn't added "for the sake of testing", it's added for the sake of proper asynchronous coding style in the source, which also facilitates testing.

Comment: I think I do understand the problem, unless you have some stronger arguments against. I never said it is arbitrary code, though the code-base can happily leave without the callback, whilst not the test. However I don't know of any other working solution as to the moment.